# How do I form separate blocks using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex, resume

This is my code:

```
results = re.finditer(r'([A-Z ?]+)\n+(.*)\n',inputfile,flags=re.MULTILINE)

for match in results:

    print match.groups()
```

i/p:

BASIC INFORMATION

Name: John

Phone No.: +91-9876543210

DOB: 21-10-1995

SKILL SET

Java

Python

o/p:
('BASIC INFORMATION', 'Name: John')
('SKILL SET', 'Java')

But required o/p:
('BASIC INFORMATION', 'Name: John', 'Phone No.: +91-9876543210', 'DOB': '21-10-1995')
('SKILL SET', 'Java',' Python')

Comment: Here how are you differentiating the SKILLSET and BASIC INFORMATION ? Why do you need regex here?

Comment: I have used ([A-Z ?]+)\n to identify BASIC INFORMATION and SKILL SET. I want to make two separate blocks that includes the information under these two headings using regular expression. @SarathSadasivanPillai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tough to get all output with regex cause your file text is not simple.

**But regex + little extra effort and you can achive this easily**

```
# This regex fetch all Titles (i.e. BASIC INFO, SKILL SET...)
results = re.findall(r"([A-Z ]{4,})", inputfile)
```

> And After little work will help you to get your desired result

```
items=[]
for z in results:
    item = inputfile[:inputfile.index(z)]
    inputfile = inputfile.replace(item,'')
    if item:
      items.append(filter(str,item.split('\n')))
items.append(filter(str,inputfile.split('\n')))
print items
```

> **OUTPUT**:
>   [ ['BASIC INFORMATION', 'Name: John', 'Phone No.: +91-9876543210', 'DOB': '21-10-1995'],
>      ['SKILL SET', 'Java',' Python']
> ]

Comment: Hey, I want the answer to be in two separate groups. BASIC INFORMATION containing Name,DOB and Phone No. and SKILL SET containing Java and Python.

Comment: SKILL SET & BASIC INFORMATION is static string in file?

Comment: no. it could be anything. This is just a sample data set.

Comment: ok then you need little extra work then regex to get result cause your file is not simple!! edited answer just check it out!

Comment: Thank you so much! Works just like I wanted it to :)

Comment: it is pretty simple regex result will get you all TITLES and then you are doing slice operation on inputfile_data to get information block. put print statement and you will get idea how it woks :)

Comment: what is this part doing?

Comment: item = inputfile[:inputfile.index(z)]

Comment: it slice your inputfile content and get you seprate block (refere this > http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `re.MULTILINE` with `re.DOTALL` so that your `.*` matches across multiple lines (yes, the flag names are somewhat misleading). You'll also want to split your resulting strings on `\n`.

And generally, probably using regexp for this task is not the best idea, this should be better:

```
import string
results = []
for line in inputfile.splitlines():
  if all(c in (string.ascii_uppercase + ' ') for c in line):
    results.append([ line ])
  elif line != '':
    results[-1].append(line)
```

Comment: how do I split it on \n? New to python. Still figuring out.

Comment: Oh wait, I worked under assumption that all lines that are not "section headers" contain lowercase letters. This is not true for `DOB: 21-10-1995`.

Comment: Its not working. Displays "None" many times. But thank you anyway!

Comment: More details (ie. what is different from your expectations) would be in order.

Comment: I have used ([A-Z ?]+)\n to identify BASIC INFORMATION and SKILL SET. I want to make two separate blocks that includes the information under these two headings using regular expression. Using the above code doesn't do that. It just prints "None" multiple times.